# nuxt on local domain?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I've setup my .hosts file to:
127.0.0.1   local.mydomain.dk

And then in my nuxt config file i've setup:

```
server: {
  port: 3000, // default: 3000
  host: 'local.mydomain.dk' // default: localhost
},
```

And last but not least, in package.json:

"dev": "nuxt --hostname local.mydomain.dk --port 3000",

However, when running npm run dev, Nuxt still starts up on localhost:3000, and not my custom domain? And if I try going to my custom domain in the browser, I get a message "Site cannot be reached"

Is there anything else to setup Nuxt for running on a local domain ?

Comment: I am at the same situation. Did you find anything that helps?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Had the same problem. My solution to this issue was to:

1. Add the following in my **etc/hosts** file:

   127.0.0.1 local.mydomain.dk
2. Flush DNS (different command in each OS)
3. Add the following in **nuxt.config.js**:

```
server: {
    port: 80,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
}
```

Now if you navigate to http://local.mydomain.dk it will work.

With this approach, I noticed that the Nuxt favicon was missing (I don't know if it introduces any other [serious] problems), so I switched to:

```
server: {
    port: 3000,
    host: 'http://local.mydomain.dk',
}
```

This time you will need to navigate to http://local.mydomain.dk:3000 to work.

Comment: How to revert this (trying to troubleshoot SSL by disabling custom domain)? I disabled my custom domain in hosts file, flushed OS dns, and configured Nuxt to _not_ use my custom domain. Yet Nuxt is still building links using the custom domain!

Comment: @MarsAndBack have you tried to clear browser's cached data?

Comment: Eventually some cache must have been cleared. I reverted commits, re-built everything and in the end there was no more problem. Was really frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

First add the host name in my etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1    local.mydomain.dk
```

For nuxt3 add below config in nuxt.config.ts file:

```
devServer: {
  port: 3000, // default: 3000
  host: 'local.mydomain.dk' // default: localhost
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to connect Telegram Oauth to nuxtjs and I wasted a lot of time trying to open a domain locally because it doesn't accept Ports. So I want to write down the method I did.

1. [Ngnix](http://nginx.org/en/download.html) Stable version dowload and install C:\ngnix folder

[image]

1. Edit  C:\ngnix\conf\nginx.conf
   [image]
2. Enter My code

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
map_hash_bucket_size 128;

    map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
        "text/html"                 epoch;
        "text/html; charset=utf-8"  epoch;
        default                     off;
    }   

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  quest.localhost;

        gzip            on;
        gzip_types      text/plain application/xml text/css application/javascript;
        gzip_min_length 1000;
     
     location / {
        expires $expires;
        proxy_redirect                      off;
        proxy_set_header Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_read_timeout          1m;
        proxy_connect_timeout       1m;
        proxy_pass                          http://localhost:3000; # set the address of the Node.js instance here
    }

}
```

3. quest.localhost here is the domain I use You can change it yourself.

[image]

4. Enter cmd and run start nginx.exe in C:\ngnix. Also do nginx -s reload against every extimole since you changed the ngnix.conf file

[image]

Now let's enter the domain name

[image]

Wow it worked